# there is a test that stuck at infinity loop can you find it?

Tags: c, testing, infinite-loop

```
int main() {
    int s, b;
    int hist[26] = { 0 };
    int hist2[26] = { 0 };
    char char1, char2;
    printf("Hello Netta, enter the letters you would like us to repeat ending with $:\n");
    scanf("%c", &char2);
    while (char2 != '$') {
        if (char2 >= 'A' && char2 <= 'Z')
            char2 = char2 + 32;
        int char3 = char2 - 'a';
        hist2[char3]++;
        scanf("%c", &char2);
        if (char2 < 0)
            break;
    }
    printf("How many times would you like to loop?\n");
    if (!scanf("%d", &s))
        return 0;

    printf("Enter the string you would like to be checked ending with $:\n");
    scanf("%c", &char1);
    if (char1 >= 'A' && char1 <= 'Z')
        char1 = char1 + 32;
     while (char1 != '$' && char1 > 0) {
         int char3 = char1 - 'a';
         hist[char3]++;
         scanf("%c", &char1);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (hist[i] > s * hist2[i]) {
            printf("Not enough letters\n");
            b = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            b = 1;
        }
    }
    if (b)
         printf("Congratulations! you have enough letters to create your song and win the Eurovision!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

//so basically this a homewrok in my university they asked us to do the program input is char and a loop and it compare it with one more input how many times you can loop each letter (no need to check that the input is true but the loop number int

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Your program has many problems:

- `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. Compare the return value to `1` in your program instead of testing `0`, which would never happen for `"%c"` anyway. Furthermore, the `char2` would not be modified if the stream is at end of file.
- You must check of `char2` is a letter before indexing into the array, otherwise you may access beyond the array boundaries and have undefined behavior.
- presentation is important: use proper indentation and spacing for the program to be readable.
- include the necessary headers such as `<stdio.h>`

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int hist[26] = { 0 };
    int hist2[26] = { 0 };
    int s;
    char c;

    printf("Hello Netta, enter the letters you would like us to repeat ending with $:\n");
    while ((scanf("%c", &c) == 1 && c != '$') {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            hist2[c - 'A']++;
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            hist2[c - 'a']++;
    }

    printf("How many times would you like to loop?\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &s) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter the string you would like to be checked ending with $:\n");
    while (scanf("%c", &c) == 1 && c != '$') {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            hist[c - 'A']++;
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            hist[c - 'a']++;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (hist[i] > s * hist2[i]) {
            printf("Not enough letters\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == 26)
         printf("Congratulations! you have enough letters to create your song and win the Eurovision!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanx man for your time but in the question we told to not check if the input is a letter but we must look at capital letters and small as one letter , and the loop number must be bigger than 0 , plus i still cant find when this program is stuck in inf-loop

Comment: You **must** check for letters, otherwise any character that is not a letter will cause undefined behavior when you index into the `hist` array. For example the first byte read by the second loop is the pending newline from the `scanf("%d", &s)`... which causes undefined behavior, possibly an infinite loop or some form of crash.

Comment: @salehmnasra:  you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.